# month wise cumulative sum

Tags: r

i have a data which is of the form :

```
month  price  name
1       200   xyz
1       300   abc
2       500   xyz
3       300   abc
4       400   cde
5       200   cde
5       100   abc
5       200   xyz
```

i want to create a cumulative sum graph month wise. Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: So we are to assume that within month, the data is in order?

Comment: yes. i only want 2 create it on the basis of the month number. so i would want a line graph showing me that corresponding to every name month wise what was the cumulative sum.

Comment: For xyz it should be like month1 = 200, month2= (month1 +2)=700 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
ts.plot(cumsum(as.vector(unlist(tapply(df$price,df$month,sum)))),
        main="cumulative month wise",
        xlab="month",ylab="cumulative",lty=3,col="purple",type="o")
```